# Plotting panel dataframe fitted vs actual as time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, panel-data

I would like to ask ho to include date variable to dataframe of all actual and fitted values from each panel data models estimators.

When using code below:

```
library(plm)
library(dplyr)

YEAR <- c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,
          2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,
          2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,
          2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
YEAR <- as.Date(YEAR)
UNIT <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
          "B", "B", "B", "B", 
          "C", "C", "C", "C",
          "D", "D", "D", "D")

Y <- sample(100:1000, 16)
X1 <- sample(10:50, 16)
X2 <- sample(20:60, 16)

data <- data.frame(YEAR, UNIT, Y)
crime.p <- pdata.frame(data,index=c("UNIT","YEAR")) 
fixedeff <- plm(log(Y)~X1 + X2,data=crime.p,model="within")
randomeff <- plm(log(Y)~X1  +X2,data=crime.p,model="random") 
firstdiff <- plm(log(Y)~X1 + X2,data=crime.p,model="fd") 

fixx_results <- data.frame(fitted = predict(fixedeff), 
  residuals = fixedeff$residuals ) %>% 
  mutate( actual = fitted + residuals, model = "fixed" ) %>% 
  select(actual, model, fitted, residuals) 

random_results <- data.frame( fitted = predict(randomeff), residuals = randomeff$residuals ) %>%
  mutate( actual = fitted + residuals, model = "random" ) %>% 
  select(actual, model, fitted, residuals) 

fd_results <- data.frame( fitted = predict(firstdiff ), residuals = firstdiff $residuals ) %>%
  mutate( actual = fitted + residuals, model = "fd" ) %>%
  select(actual, model, fitted, residuals) 

fitted_res_all <- rbind(fixx_results, random_results, fd_results)
fitted_res_all
```

`fitted_res_all` dataframe does not contain Date varaible and I dont know how to added it there. I know it can be done "by-hand" but I would like to have it as universal as possible so it can be reused in the future.

Problem is also that each panel data estimator have different numbers of observations.
What I would like to end up with is a time series plots of actual and fitted but to have variable date on X axes, in this dataset we have early data, but sometimes he would have monthly

Answer (score 0):

adding the date to your dataframe should solve your problem

````
fixx_results <- data.frame(fitted = predict(fixedeff), 
                           residuals = fixedeff$residuals, date = rownames(crime.p)) %>% 
  mutate( actual = fitted + residuals, model = "fixed" ) %>% 
  select(actual, model, fitted, residuals, date) 

random_results <- data.frame( fitted = predict(randomeff), residuals = randomeff$residuals, date = rownames(crime.p)) %>%
  mutate( actual = fitted + residuals, model = "random" ) %>% 
  select(actual, model, fitted, residuals, date) 

fd_results <- data.frame( fitted = predict(firstdiff), residuals = firstdiff $residuals, date = rownames(crime.p)[4:length(crime.p)] ) %>%
  mutate( actual = fitted + residuals, model = "fd" ) %>%
  select(actual, model, fitted, residuals, date) ```
````

Comment: Thank you, but what approach would you choose to plot results? I am kind of confused because dates have cross-sectional information as well

Comment: And Also on first_differences estimator Date does not change cross-sectional units - That is way I posted the question, I dont know how to account for it

Comment: I would use ggplot2 (linechart) for plotting http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/128-plot-time-series-data-using-ggplot/. With ggplot you can use facets with different x-values for your dates